# CSS: How to wrap a line of text backwards, so the final text always fills the entire width of the container?

Tags: html, css

I have a container with a bottom-border. For ease, let's say it has a fixed width of 200px. The text within it is 250px wide.

How can I wrap the text so that the last text always sits flush with the bottom-border, and when the text exceeds the container's width, only one word is pushed to the line above (rather than the full line of text being on line 1 and the remaining ~50px of text is on the bottom line)?

Imagine something like `text-align: bottom` or similar, so that the words "the container" in the snippet below would sit on the line.

```html
<div style="width:200px;border-bottom:1px solid blue;">
  <p>This is the text is wider than the container</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not possible with CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking can not be done with CSS alone.

Just for fun, here is a solution that would be awful for SEO and should probably never see the light of day.

Take your text, wrap each word in a span, reverse the order of the words, reattach to the DOM.

From there, you can achieve your desired layout with flex.

```js
const wrapText = document.querySelector('.wrap-text');

wrapText.innerHTML = wrapText.textContent.split(' ').map(function(x) {
    return '<span>' + x + '</span>';
}).reverse().join('');
```

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

p span {
  margin-right: .3em; 
}

p:hover span {
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;border-bottom:1px solid blue;">
  <p>This text is wider than the container and will flow normally.</p>
</div>

<div style="width:200px;border-bottom:1px solid blue;">
  <p class="wrap-text">This text is wider than the container and will flow in an unnatural manner.</p>
</div>
```