# Creating a bottom border that is the length of the bottom row of child spans

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**TL:DR - I have a set of spans that reverse wrap in a container div and I need a "border line" that is the width of only the bottom set of spans. (The solution can use any combination of css, html, js)**

To give a little context, I am using these span boxes that get made with some JS so I can have reverse wrap and fill in the bottom lines first.

The JS in question:

```js
x = document.getElementsByClassName("ipsumNumber");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  const wrapText = x[i];
  wrapText.innerHTML = wrapText.textContent
    .split(" ")
    .map(function (y) {
      return "<span>" + y + "</span>";
    })
    .reverse()
    .join("");
}
```

I want to have a bottom bar that is an arbitrary number of pixels wider then the bottom line of spans. My current tactic is to use a mass of `@media` in a css file.

Somthing like this:

```css
.ipsumHolder {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 0.3em;
    position: absolute;
}
.ipsum::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: -5.5px;
    margin-right: 0.3em;
    padding-left: 0.3em;
    padding-right: 0.3em;
    border-bottom: 10px solid blue;
    width: 80%;
    color: transparent;
    bottom: 0;
}

p.ipsumNumber{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: center;
}

@media (max-width: 852px) {
    #ipsum::after {
        line-height: 2em;
        content: "Neque porro quisquam";
    }
}

@media (max-width: 666px) {
    #ipsum::after {
        line-height: 2em;
        content: "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem";
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #ipsum::after {
        line-height: 1em;
        content: "quisquam est qui dolorem";
    }
}

@media (max-width: 428px) {
    #ipsum::after {
        line-height: 3em;
        content: "qui dolorem";
    }
}
```

Perfect fit:
[image: Perfect Fit]

Non-perfect fit (last line is the largest):
[image: Non-Perfect]

Span boxes:
[image: Span Boxes]

```html
<div class="ipsumHolder">
  <p id="ipsum" class="ipsumNumber">
    <span>ipsum</span><span>dolorem</span><span>qui</span><span>est</span><span>quisquam</span><span>porro</span><span>Neque</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

This is horrible and disgusting  (not to mention there are about 4 of these text boxes per page and I would have to do this for 4 different files)!

I know there must be a better way to this, but i just can't think of it. I have not found a way to do "`width: 100%;`" and only fill for the bottom row.

Comment: Can't you wrap all those spans in a parent span and put the border on that?

Comment: @charlietfl mabey let me try

Comment: That would still apply the border to the width of the **widest** line, not neccecarily the **bottom** line of `<span>`s. I'm not sure there is a non-js way of doing what you want, and even the js version i picture would be quite tacky; i realise you said JS is ok, but i have to wonder, what are you really trying to build ? (ps: i imagine by *reverse overflow*  you ment *reverse wrap* right?)

Comment: @Raxi it's not hard to isolate each line of spans to wrap them

Comment: Ya, just tried and @Raxi is correct :(

Comment: @charlietfl could you send a code example on how to isolate each responsive line of spans.

Comment: Create a runnable version by clicking on `<>` in editor, then it's super easy to copy whole things to an answer. OK to use jquery?

Comment: It is hard to isolate them (unless i misunderstand the question); as far as i can tell, you don't know ahead of time how many `<span>`s fit in a physical line.

Comment: @charlietfl jquery is good

Comment: @Raxi No but after they get rendered you can walk through them checking offsets. when the y axis jumps you start a new line

Comment: @Raxi correct, I have no way to know how many spans there will be. I was trying to find an over arching solution.

Comment: are you ready for some CSS hacks?

Comment: @charlietfl agreed, with a script you can ; but just double-bagging it, which i think was your suggestion, isn't enough.

Comment: @Cutwow475 If you want a script solution; I think the following answers solve essentially the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49043684/how-to-calculate-the-amount-of-flexbox-items-in-a-row   ; that said, personally i would wonder if there wasn't a completely different solution to whatever niche the `<span>`group fills.

Comment: @Raxi the spans are only there for the reverse wrap. I found no other "clean' way to do it if I have a p element and want it to be responsive. I will continue looking.

The answer I found was: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63781033/css-how-to-wrap-a-line-of-text-backwards-so-the-final-text-always-fills-the-en

Comment: Well `<p>`aragraphs inherently auto-wrap don't they, though using an entirely separate mechanism than regular inline/block elements. That said, i cannot really picture what role this component plays in the overall site/app, so it is likely i'm missing something. I guess if the **reverse**-wrapping is the key issue then yes, i don't think there is a *bottom-to-top* property, the way there is for LTR / RTL (right to left) text.

Comment: @Raxi it is not a mission critical part of my application. Just a stylistic choice which I want to be repeated a bunch of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a CSS-only hacky solution. Resize the container to notice the responsiveness

```css
.ipsumNumber {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  gap: 5px; /* the gap */
}
.ipsumHolder {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden; /* we need to hide the overflow */
  resize: horizontal;
  background: #000; /* main background */
}
.ipsumNumber span {
  position: relative;
}
.ipsumNumber span:before,
.ipsumNumber span:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
}
/* your underline */
.ipsumNumber span:before {
  inset: 100% -5px auto; /* 5px same as gap, you can use bigger if you want but not smaller  */
  background: blue;
}
/* the hack that will hide the non-needed unreline */
.ipsumNumber span:after {
  inset: auto -200vmax 100%; /* 200vmax is a very big value */
  background: #000; /* same as main background */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ipsumHolder">
  <p id="ipsum" class="ipsumNumber">
    <span>ipsum</span><span>dolorem</span><span>qui</span><span>est</span><span>quisquam</span><span>porro</span><span>Neque</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is really well executed; however, it dosn't appear to work when using `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;` which is the main problem I am having.

Comment: @Cutwow475 check the update

Comment: PERFECT! Just needed to add a `flex-direction: row-reverse;` and it looks like this solution will work. Thank you!